# VPNC & network-manager

Tags: networking, vpn

I don't seem to be able to add VPNC connections in the network manager. I've installed vpnc and vpnc-scripts, neither has added the VPNC option to the menu to add a VPN connection. I can run vpnc from terminal (with sudo) to connect to a VPN, but this is non-ideal.

Can anyone advise how to add a VPNC network connection using the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added `network-manager-vpnc` and `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` with `apt-get install`. After that I am able to add the Connection with GUI tools.

Comment: Ugh now you mention it I remember something like this from a former incarnation. Will try it shortly, thank you.